When is it appropriate to critique asker's methods? When is it appropriate to tell the asker to work for themselves?
I just offered this answer on a user's question: Analyzing review rating using R STM package - sample balance issue and I feel a pang of guilt discrediting an article they cite. I tried to provide the many reasons why I feel the article is nonsense. My hope in doing this is that the OP will take these critiques to heart and better learn how to use Google Scholar or PubMed to research statistical questions. What I do not hope to see is that the OP asks me to provide a better article for him or her - it's not my goal to be the expert in the particular topic. We have access to all the necessary tools. I sincerely believe I can help by showing him or her how to use them.
On other forums, I frequently see and am annoyed by similar holier-than-thou dismissive answers, such as Q:"How do I make my cookies soft and fluffy?" A: "Buy them from your grocery store." which is perhaps funny... the first time, but completely useless every time.
I wonder if any supercontributors have guidance or advice to share on the question(s):

When is it appropriate to critique an asker's methods?
When is it appropriate to push the asker to figure some things out for themselves?


I have to regard you as a supercontributor; reputation is not everything, but yours is still bigger than mine.

Related: What to do about "wrong" questions?

I think tone matters here and I think yours was fine. For me at least, rather than an attack on the user, it reads more like a warning against the growing problem of bad literature, which is a helpful message (+1).

One thing to keep in mind is that answers are not just for the OP but for any later readers of the post. Indeed this was made explicit by the founders of stackexchange ― it's not just a site (or a network of sites) for answering every question that comes along on its own terms, but a site for building and curating good questions and canonical answers, to help everyone with a similar issue.
Naturally you will seek to help the OP along the way, but meeting their needs is not the primary function of the answer.
The site is built around gamifying that aspect (helping people other than the person asking it) in several ways.
In my opinion it was correct to do so. Indeed it was a major motivator in bringing me to the site regularly in the first place; I started answering stats questions on the internet in 1992 (initially on Usenet and a few mailing lists, though I forget which came first), having grown frustrated at answering the same few dozen questions over and over in person in the late 80s, only helping one person with the time invested in each answer. I started answering on the internet in the hopes of building a store of answers in accessible electronic form that didn't have to be given anew every time; where new askers of essentially the same question could be pointed to my previous answers.
When stackexchange came along it seemed to be a good match to my motivation for answering such questions on the internet.
As far as I have been able to judge (looking at reputation accumulation over time and also using the data site many times), the overwhelming majority of my answer views accrue long after the OP has moved on.
According to stackexchange, my answers have been viewed 25 million times (bots are excluded from that count by the way). I have posted fewer than 5000 answers, so that aim (to help more than one person with a single answer) appears to have succeeded. I'd say that overall, a very large proportion of those views came after the few days the OP might have cared about what was contained in the answer; for many of my most viewed answers perhaps more than 90% of the views came after the first few days. Not everyone who counted as a view or partial view* would have benefited from it of course, but in any case pretty clearly the majority of the benefit of an answer is to people other than the OP.
Let us imagine that you regard the OP to be within their rights to use any analysis they see fit, indeed, you may even regard them to be in a position to capably judge it for themselves.
Nevertheless, if the analysis may be inadvisable - or perhaps potentially misleading, dangerous, or only suitable under some certain conditions, to let it pass without comment is a disservice to later readers, who may often be statistically naive. To just "stick to the question" that was asked can easily lead to it being taken by such a reader as a tacit acceptance of that choice as reasonable practice.
Consequently, my view is it is almost always appropriate to comment about the advisability of something under discussion. If it's based on questionable research, raise those questions. If it has some dangers or hidden traps, mention them. It might not justify a long discussion perhaps, but some kind of caveat is definitely in order, and as a degree of editorial comment as might be a useful guide to later, potentially naive readers, is typically called for.
You also ask about pushing a reader to figure things out for themselves; I think that's very much a matter of context. There are certainly times that it's appropriate - self-study questions are a good example, where the OP is expected to show good faith efforts in that vein, and receive additional hints and guidance when they do. However, there are certainly times when a direct answer may be more suitable.
It's not always obvious where to draw the line, and a certain degree of tolerance of each others choices in drawing it might be needed. Where strong differences of opinion occur, as would be inevitable from time to time when judgements differ more substantively, reasonable discussion here or on chat might be worth taking up.

* they allocate fractions of views across multiple answers via an algorithm

Strong agreement here from me, unsurprisingly I hope. Seemingly the hardest thing for many people new to SE to understand is that it is not a helpline and above all that posters are not entitled to an answer as or in the form that they expect or request.  Long-term dedication to the goals of SE has a perhaps inevitable side-effect that some posters will be disappointed, irritated or annoyed at not getting the answers they seek. The limiting cases What should I do in my project? Why do I get puzzling results? What code should I use? are all common but often hard or impossible to answer.

When is it appropriate to critique an asker's methods?
Short answer: Often.
Longer answer: The OP retains one right while their post remains on CV, the right to accept any answer that satisfies them. Otherwise the rest of the community retain most of the power and above all most of the responsibility for a thread.
There is a range between extremes. A question that appears utterly vague or confused or wrong-headed or a duplicate may be best closed in the short term and at worst deleted in the long term. It's not at all a good idea to edit a question to be a different question, even if you are convinced that the original question is vague, confused, or wrong-headed and you are confident that you know a better question. It is often a good idea to make cosmetic edits to tidy up a messy question to improve its chances of survival. It is often a good idea to indicate through comments how a question is lacking and ideally how it might be improved (e.g. by giving a data example).
If the question is at heart a good question with difficulties or ambiguities, then different possible replies are better explored through comments or answers.
Zero tolerance should be applied to spam, complete irrelevance, or filth. (Bizarre memory: I think I once commented that e.g. a question on marriage guidance would be out of place here, only to see one such appear shortly afterwards. I can't substantiate this, as the question disappeared promptly.)
Important detail: Cross Validated is more tolerant of comments and different answers than some other parts of Stack Exchange. Even experts in statistics or machine learning are usually wrong in some sense according to some of the other experts.
When is it appropriate to push the asker to figure some things out for themselves?
Short answer: Often.
Longer answer:
The OP should take most responsibility for knowing about and explaining their data and their research problem and for substantive interpretation. By accident if not design, a thread may attract attention of people with expertise in say econometrics, medical statistics or environmental statistics, but it is not a major goal of CV to provide subject-matter interpretations.
The OP should take complete responsibility for trying to solve homework problems or other assignments under the heading self-study.
The OP should not try to outsource
their needs

to study textbooks or other teaching materials themselves (we don't provide individual tutorials or mini-reviews on request)

to identify papers and other sources in their subject-matter field

to plan the analysis for a complete project

to identify and if needed to write software code for their analysis.



I don't know what AdamO wanted to mean by supercontributor, but I feel it is reflected in the experience and wisdom articulated in this answer (than say rep), Nick, so, yeh you fall in that category (+1). (I initially thought I would delete my post but as it got a vote, I am refraining from that.)

(Don't know about what you meant by "supercontributors") here is my two cent:
Stack Exchange is a q&a site and not a discussion forum where comments can go on and on and at point deviating from the topic in hand.
You answered OP's query with a reference to another thread. Then you discussed why the cited papers are not to be taken without pinch of salt. So you answered OP's query in a way you deemed apt.
The question is not about which paper other than what are cited should be relevant -- you simply indicated the papers cited are not to be trusted blindly and that came as an assessment while you answered.
It's not upon you to direct OP how to research properly in that vein. That was not the question at the first place. That appeared as an observation and if any additional query arises, that should be separately dealt with, plausibly as an altogether different question, perhaps say, a reference-request.
So, whenever it is required to make OP aware the methods they are following are having caveats, that should be done.
And it is not an imposition that you have to follow what OP dictates. You can merely state, in light of any said request that is not in the purview of the present context, or not in the structure of a single q&a framework, to OP that this is not the proper medium or mode to entertain further.
